# images not imported through csv in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, csv, importexport, import-products

I tried to import products through **import/export**, everything gets imported but not image.

What I did was:

1. Flushed cache and re-index
2. Media folder provided permissions to 777
3. Place all images in `var/media/import`
4. CSV column contains `image,small_image,thumbnail,_media_image,media_gallery`  & `gallery`
   with values like `/A30412.JPG`
5. Only the placeholder image is shown in the frontend.

Any solutions, based on above scenario. Please suggest.

Comment: I have had some trouble with Magento data profiles in importing images and other advanced features. I suggest that you use https://aionhill.com/product-import-magmi.

Answer (score 1):

The correct path to place images in is `media/import` for images by default. First move all the images from your `var/media/import` to the above.

Secondly remove the trailing `/` from your image names and use `A30412.JPG` instead. Make sure your image names match exactly with the ones provided in your CSV - a `.JPG` file won't match against a `.jpg` image in your CSV for example.

Lastly, I would suggest using Magmi for importations into Magento 1. It requires some modifications over the default Import/Export & Dataflow to get it working but provides better error outputs and will create attribute/categories on the fly for you. More information can be found at https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git